# CDKTF Iterator On AWS Resources

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform-cdk

I've gone through the source code of CDKTF TerraformIterator, and the AWS Subnets to try and find a way to iterate over Subnet when setting for_each. I'm not sure how to do this as the iterator requires a list of strings and I don't see anything that would return subnet ids from that class. Here is some Python pseudo code:

```
public_subnets = Subnet(self, 'default-public',
        for_each = public_subnet_iterator,
        availability_zone_id = public_subnet_iterator.get_string('availability_zone'),
        cidr_block = public_subnet_iterator.get_string('CIDR'),
        vpc_id = default_vpc.id
        tags = Tags.commons_with_name('default-public')
)

route_table = RouteTable(self, 'public-subnets',
        vpc_id = default_vpc.id,
        RouteTableRoute(
            cidr_block = '0.0.0.0/0',
            gateway_id = default_gateway.id
        ),
        tags = Tags.commons_with_name('public-subnet-routing')
)

routable_subnets = TerraformIterator.fromList(public_subnets.?????)
RouteTableAssociation(self, 'public-subnet-routes',
    for_each = routable_subnets,
    etc...
)
```

How can I iterate over the subnets to generate these route table associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported in CDKTF, but will likely change in the upcoming version 0.16. See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/issues/2024 and https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/pull/2739 for more context. Until it's supported you would need to use an [escape hatch](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/resources#escape-hatch-for-dynamic-blocks) to make it work or if the `publicSubnetIterator` is using a static list you could also use a for loop.